# Socket.IO-Client in angular not receiving all the messages sent by server(Kafka-consumer) node.js

Tags: angular, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafkajs, socket.io-client

I am building an Apache Kafka application where Producer (built on Dotnet Api) successfully published **90,045** messages to topic and Consumer (Built on Node.js) has received all of them. But when consumer is sending those messages to Angular UI through socket.io, following weird things I observe.
1. Angular UI only receives 6921 messages and it does vary every time but never cross 10000
2. In UI Browser console, I could see these 6921 messages multiple times. It creating duplicate
messages.
3. In UI there is delay happening to receive these consumer messages.

Consumer (Node.js)

```
const topic = 'kafka-topic-3'
  const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: 'demo-consumer-group' })
  const run = async () => {
    await consumer.connect()
    await consumer.subscribe({ topic })
    await consumer.run({
      //partitionsConsumedConcurrently:10,
      eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
        const prefix = `${topic}[${partition} | ${message.offset}] / ${message.timestamp}`
        io.emit('Kafka-message', message.value.toString('utf8'));
        console.log('Received', prefix, message.value.toString('utf8'));
      },
    })
  }

  run().catch(e => console.error(`[example/consumer] ${e.message}`, e))
  module.exports = run;
```

Angular Service

```
getLiveDataFromTopic1() { 
    console.log('called getLiveDataFromTopic1');
    let observable = new Observable(observer => {
      this.socket = io.connect(this.url);
      this.socket.on('Kafka-message', (data:any) => {       
        observer.next(data);
      });
      return () => {
        this.socket.off('Kafka-message');
        this.socket.disconnect();
      }
    })
    return observable;
  }
```

Angular Component

```
connection: any;
  messages=new Array();
  message: string = "";
  totalMessages: number = 0;

  constructor(private kafkaService: KafkaClientService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('ngonit:,called');
    this.connection = this.kafkaService.getLiveDataFromTopic1().subscribe(msg => {      
      this.messages.push(msg);
      console.log('this.messages',this.messages);
      // this.totalMessages++;
      // this.message = this.message + "<li>" + msg + " </li>";
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.connection.unsubscribe();  
    this.messages.forEach(s=>s.unsubscribe());
    this.messages=[];  
  }
```

Comment: Please paste the code in your question instead of screenshots. And consider adding a simple **reproducible** sample to help people who are going to answer.

Comment: I have share the code. Could you please help now ?

Comment: @ShahinSorkh could please help me to solve this ?

Comment: I don't know angular enough to answer your question, so, no I cannot.